# Spring Data JPA + JpaSpecificationExecutor + NamedEntityGraph

Tags: spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

I have two Entities. Parent and Child.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
}

@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Child.parentObj", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNodes("parentObj"))
public class Child{
//blah blah blah

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
Parent parentObj;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CHILD_ID")
Set<Address> address
//blah blah blah
}
```

ChildRepository.java

```
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>{

     @EntityGraph(value="Child.parentObj")
     public List<Child> findAll(Specification<Child> spec);
}
```

I am trying to find child entities by criteria and it should always have parent.

I am getting exception that it is trying to find parentObj in Address table.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parentObj of: com.xxx.Address [..]
```

I found this link and tried solution given by Joep but same error.

[Spring Data JPA + JpaSpecificationExecutor + EntityGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291143/spring-data-jpa-jpaspecificationexecutor-entitygraph)

what am I missing. I am not able to understand why/how i limit to look for parentObj in just Child Object as Address has no reference to Parent.

I am doing search by Address.street.

I have tried ad-hoc entity graph too. exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parentObj of: com.xxx.Address 

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parentObj of: com.xxx.Address
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.EntityGraphQueryHint.getFromElements(EntityGraphQueryHint.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.EntityGraphQueryHint.toFromElements(EntityGraphQueryHint.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:665)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunctionOrSubselect(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4905)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4606)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to  find Child entries by criteria search and get ParentObj for each child. I wanted to do join and not individual select for Parent. I was trying to solve that by using EntityGraph but it didn't work. As @EKlavya pointed out Specification and EntityGraph don't work togather.

The way I solved was:

```
root.fetch("parentObj", JOIN.LEFT);
```

in my toPredicate method. this will get Child entity with Parent in 1 query.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Child.parentObj` as Entity graph name but you named the entity graph as `Child.parent`. Use

```
@EntityGraph(value="Child.parent")
```

**Without @NamedEntityGraph**

we can define an ad-hoc entity graph, without @NamedEntityGraph just use

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"parentObj"})
```

**Update:**
Entity graph and specification both are not working together.
There is a way to solve this. Don't do eager for parent fetch child only first then make a list of child ids from child's and get parents using in clause query using child ids. Total only 2 queries needed. If you want to solve this using 1 query use DSL to do raw query.

Comment: There was typing error for parentOBj. I have fixed it. I have tried ad-hoc entity graph as well. I am not able to understand why/how i limit to look for parentObj in just Child Object as Address has no reference to Parent.

Comment: Similer error. stacktrace is diferent. but it is looking for parentObj  in Address.I started with ad-hoc entity graph and then moved to NamedEntityGraph in hope for solution.

Comment: Can you add detail stacktrace for adhoc  graph also

Comment: updated original post with details. thanks for help and time.

Comment: Add full stacktrace(not just 1 line) and Parent entity class also

Comment: added more details.

Comment: Oh ! I didn't see that you are using the specification,  Entity graph and specification both are not working together. Sorry bro

Comment: IS it a fact? I didn't find any examples so I going to trust you. So can you suggest to tackle this problem any other way. I mean use Specification on Child table bcs I have bunch properties on Child that I can serach by and result should be join of Child and Parent. Initally I was not going for join and relying on individual queries done by jpa to populate Child but as moved to more testing I realised that if I get 50 child objects then there will be 50 select for parent. I want to avoid that.

Comment: You can fetch child first then make a list of child ids and get  parent using in query. Currently I don't get any better way

Comment: If I don't do entity graph, it used to find all Child entries and then each Parent bcs of FetchType.EAGER. But that is very expensive as I may find lot of Child entiries and that means it will perform that many select on Parent table. I dont want that.

Comment: Don't do eager for parent fetch child only first then make a list of child ids from child's  and get parent using in clause query using child ids. Only 2 query

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to do with 1. I am updating old code to spring and it does with 1 query so anything more than 1 query is kind of defeating the purpose of upgrade.

Comment: Then use DSL query (raw) then it is possible

Comment: thanks. i am going to keep this question open to see someone else has any other ideas.

Comment: The 2 query idea is not that great. If the first query selects too much ids, it may explode the cost of the second query if it makes a WHERE id IN (ids-selected-in-first-query)